# How to position the bootstrap modal in center without getting any scroll bars?

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to position the modal in the center of the screen always.
To do so , I added the following CSS class to the modal :

```
.modal-position {
           position: fixed;
           left: 50% !important;
           top: 50% !important;
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

But its not getting exactly centered and **on small screen size a vertical scroll bar appears beside it though there is enough space for the modal**.

JS fiddle for the same : https://jsfiddle.net/86n9pbat/

Comment: problem with css you apply on bootstrap pop-up model.Please follow this link `https://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc`

Comment: This is actually a common problem for bootstrap. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422223/bootstrap-3-modal-vertical-position-center) duplicate question. The most accepted answer is outlined in the codepen provided by @ManjeetThakur (https://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `overflow: hidden` in your css body/modal when modal is open?

Comment: This will only work with !important since modal by default has overflow-y set to auto

Comment: not really, all you need to do is make sure that you have higher points/priority in your selector, like try using id instead of class @Dana

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal what do you mean clip extra data? having it visible will make excess characters or dom elements still be visible on your dontainer

Comment: @perseusl : Thankyou :)

Comment: overriding the overflow property to VISIBLE helped me remove the extra scroll bar and hence accpeting this as answer. If you dont want to show the data you can make it overflow : hidden

Comment: @Dana : Perseusl is correct. Setting it to important is not required. Just a hig priority selector is enough

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog myModal">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.myModal
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin:auto;
  display:table;
  max-width:50%;
}
.myModal .modal-content
{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

pretty much the same code. I have added a **myModal** class to **modal-dialog** and the CSS..
[link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/GEWVJw)
hope this helps..

Comment: On screen size below 768px, the modal is only vertically centered and not horizontally centered.

Comment: hi try setting the max-width property.. updated the code above.

Comment: After 768px its not in centered after updating the property

Comment: can i have a screenshot?

Comment: .modal-dialog class width is set to auto below 768px. and above 768px it is fixed to 600px; ... better solution is to handle the width with a media query below 768px.. hope this helps..

Comment: Yes you are correct. It was happening because of the width. Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score -1):

No need for the above code.
Bootstrap modal is responsive by default.
If you want to adjust the **width** just change it on **modal-content** class in your css file.

Comment: Yes it is responsive. But  I am trying to poisition it to center

Comment: try reducing modal-content width.